# Reactjs ERROR (Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: loadUser is not a function at SignInFunc.js:31:1)

Tags: reactjs

1. I created a **loadUser** and **onRouteChange** function so as i can pass it on my SignIn.js file, but it shows me ERROR: loadUser and onRouteChange are not functions.

```
    const App = () => {

    const[ route, setRoute ] = useState('home')
    const[ user, setUser ] = useState({
        id: '',
        name: '',
        email: '',
        entries: 0,
        joined: ''
    })

    const loadUser = (data) => {
        setUser({
            id: data.id,
            name: data.name,
            email: data.email,
            entries: data.entries,
            joined: data.joined
        })
    }

    const onRouteChange = (route) => {
        setRoute(route);
    }

        return (
            <>
               <SignIn loadUser={loadUser} onRouteChange={onRouteChange} />
               <SignUp loadUser={loadUser} onRouteChange={onRouteChange} />  
            </>
        );
        export default App;
```

2. On my SignIn.js file i passed **loadUser** and **onRouteChange** as parameters, but the errors still occur

```
    const SignIn = ({ loadUser, onRouteChange}) => {

    const onSubmitSignIn = () => {
        fetch('http://localhost:3001/signin', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: signInEmail,
                password: signInPassword
            })
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(user => {
                if (user.id) {
                    {loadUser(user)}
                    {onRouteChange('home')}
                } else {
                    setMessage('Wrong Username or Password')
                }
            })
    }

        return (
                <div>
                     .......
                </div>
        )
     }

     export default SignIn;
```

Comment: Can you also include a codesandbox with a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-forked-1dho4?file=/App.js

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-allen-sg8zo?file

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the extraneous parenthesis

```
 const onSubmitSignIn = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/signin', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email: signInEmail,
            password: signInPassword
        })
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(user => {
            if (user.id) {
                loadUser(user)
                onRouteChange('home')
            } else {
                setMessage('Wrong Username or Password')
            }
        })
}
```